# innerHTML message not working

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

in a register form I have php validating a password and sending the message "good" back to the div "password_feedback". in the if statement if password_feedback == "good" then display "password good" in the "check" div(not shown in the code snippet).

I have done the exact same thing with "username" and "re-enter password" and they work fine and I have added them together into one if statement. but password and email don't work despite me doing the exact same thing with them all. is there something I'm not aware of causing the problem.

```html
<script type='text/javascript'>

  function check_info(){
    var password_good = document.getElementById('password_feedback').innerHTML;
 
    if(password_good == "good" ){
      document.getElementById("check").innerHTML = "password good";
    } else{
      document.getElementById("check").innerHTML = "bad job ";
    } 
  }

</script>
```

```html
<input name="password" type="password" id="password_input" value="">
<div id="password_feedback"> </div>
```

Comment: Please indent your code properly. Also, we don't need the `<script>` tags, we can see that it's JS.

Answer (score 1):

The problems:

- You are not binding you function to the change event of the password field
- You are checking the value with `innerHTML` instead of `value`
- You are using wrong IDs in `document.getElementById()`

You code fixed:

```js
var password_input = document.getElementById('password_input');

password_input.onchange = password_input.onkeyup = function() {

  var password_good = (password_input.value === "good");

  document.getElementById("check").innerHTML = password_good ? 'Good' : 'Bad';

}
```

```html
<input name="password" type="password" id="password_input">

<div id="check"></div>
```